# Match username (array) to email (array)

Tags: excel, vba

Using Excel 2013. My first post after years of finding and adapting.

I'm trying to match the current App user, ie "John Smith", to his email address "jsmith@work.com".

Using two strings: 1 for users (1 to 3), the other eaddress(1 To 3).
I want to get the current user's email address for use in separate Sub that CCs the current user on an email.

I tried a `For Each i In user`, and set eName to `eaddress(i)`.
This returned only the *last* listed user/email.

```
Private Sub (useremail)
Dim user (1 To 3), eaddress (1 To 3), fullName, eName As String

fullName = Application.UserName
user(1) = "John Smith"
user(2) = "Debbie Adams"
user(3) = "Karen Jones"

eaddress(1) = "jsmith@work.com"
eaddress(2) = "dadams@work.com"
eaddress(3) = "kjones@work.com"

For i = 1 To 3
    'For Each i In user
        fullName = user(i)
        eName = eaddress(i)
    'Exit For
    debug.print "User is " & fullname & "email to " & eName
Next i
```

Looking to get the eaddress/eName of the current user (for use in separate Sub to email file).

Comment: need to move your `debug.print` inside your loop.

Comment: @tigeravatar Ok, moved d.p inside, and it correctly matches FOR EACH user/address. I need to extract just 1 Match. I think i need an IF user(i) Then eName = eaddress, but i'm not getting it right.

Comment: Are you hard coding these username/addresses, or are they being pulled from a location in the file?  your code indicates these are hard coded, but that may be just for the example.

Comment: @Cyril Names and emails are hardcoded. May eventually move to a hidden sheet in the workbook, but for now...

Comment: I feel like the answers are good enough it doesn't warrant mine variant. But in a more robust project in the future, you might want to consider creating your own class of 'User' and create a Collection of users.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a [`Dictionary`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/dictionary-object) to make this easier

```
Private Sub UsereMail()
    Dim dictInfo, fullName

    fullName = Application.UserName

    Set dictInfo = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    dictInfo.Add "John Smith", "jsmith@work.com"
    dictInfo.Add "Debbie Adams", "dadams@work.com"
    dictInfo.Add "Karen Jones", "kjones@work.com"

    If dictInfo.Exists(fullName) Then
        Debug.Print "User is " & fullName & " email to " & dictInfo(fullName)
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks @pankaj Jaju! Works like a charm. Just have to add all my users...but this is easy! (Sorry, i'm too low a rep for my vote to count!)

Answer (score 0):

Using your original array-based approach:

```
Sub tester()
    Debug.Print "John Smith", UserEmail("John Smith") '>> jsmith@work.com
    Debug.Print "John Brown", UserEmail("John Brown") '>> [blank]
End Sub


Private Function UserEmail(userName As String) As String

    Dim user(1 To 3), eaddress(1 To 3), m

    user(1) = "John Smith"
    user(2) = "Debbie Adams"
    user(3) = "Karen Jones"

    eaddress(1) = "jsmith@work.com"
    eaddress(2) = "dadams@work.com"
    eaddress(3) = "kjones@work.com"

    m = Application.Match(userName, user, 0)
    If Not IsError(m) Then UserEmail = eaddress(m)

End Function
```

Comment: Thanks @Tim Williams! with the error catch is also great!

Answer (score 0):

Another dictionary based approach where the list of users does not have to be in the same order as the email addresses.

```
Option Explicit

Sub Test()
Dim user(1 To 3)            As String
Dim eaddress(1 To 3)        As String
Dim user_dic                As Scripting.Dictionary

user(1) = "John Smith"
user(2) = "Debbie Adams"
user(3) = "Karen Jones"

eaddress(1) = "jsmith@work.com"
eaddress(2) = "dadams@work.com"
eaddress(3) = "kjones@work.com"

Set user_dic = MatchUsersToEmail(eaddress, user)

Debug.Print eaddress(1), user_dic.Item(eaddress(1))
Debug.Print eaddress(2), user_dic.Item(eaddress(2))
Debug.Print eaddress(3), user_dic.Item(eaddress(3))

End Sub

Public Function MatchUsersToEmail(ByRef email_array() As String, ByRef user_array() As String) As Scripting.Dictionary
' Returns a scripting dictionary where the email address returns the user name
Dim my_users                As Scripting.Dictionary
Dim my_user                 As Variant
Dim my_email                As Variant
Dim my_name()               As String
Dim my_key                  As String
    Set my_users = New Scripting.Dictionary

    For Each my_email In email_array
        ' Add the email address as the key
        my_users.Add Key:=CStr(my_email), Item:=vbNullString

    Next

    For Each my_user In user_array
        my_name = Split(LCase$(my_user))
        my_key = Left$(my_name(0), 1) & my_name(1) & "@work.com"
        my_users.Item(my_key) = my_user

    Next

    Set MatchUsersToEmail = my_users

End Function
```